# Java EE, purpose of an Object instance inside a contructor of another Class

Tags: java, mysql, constructor

I was watching the code of an advanced student and I saw something that I haven't seen in any tutorial. An object was instantiated inside the constructor of another class. Something like this:

```
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    ...

    public Student() {
        Course course = new Course();
    }
}
```

The app uses a database that has Course and Student tables. What is the purpose of that? Does it have something to do with the foreign key?

Comment: `Class` is a type in java : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: Well may I say it's something common or at least normal. Let's say each student have a SchoolBag. Then instantiating a Student requires the creation of a SchoolBag object.

Comment: If you meant `Class` to stand for the type of class a student takes, you should [edit] your post and choose a different name in your example. `Class` is a standard classname in Java and you shouldn't call one of your own classes by that name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, it is about the following line in the constructor of the `Student` class:

```
Course course = new Course();
```

Seeing this line alone, I would say that this doesn't make any sense because the `course` object will not be seen outside of the `Student` constructor.

But there are some people who execute some code in a constructor. So I guess some code might be executed in the constructor of `Course` class.

Even though it is possible to do so (executing code in a constructor) it is not advisable to do anything in the constructor except for the purpose of **constructing/creating an instance of that class**.

Answer (score -2):

Instances of the class Class represent classes and interfaces in a running Java application. An enum is a kind of class and an annotation is a kind of interface. Every array also belongs to a class that is reflected as a Class object that is shared by all arrays with the same element type and number of dimensions. The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class objects.
Class has no public constructor. Instead Class objects are constructed automatically by the Java Virtual Machine as classes are loaded and by calls to the defineClass method in the class loader.

The following example uses a Class object to print the class name of an object:

```
 void printClassName(Object obj) {
     System.out.println("The class of " + obj +
                        " is " + obj.getClass().getName());
 }
```

Comment: I think the use of the name `Class` was an unfortunate choice by the OP.  I take it to mean "class" as in "school class" for the student.

Comment: An object of the class Course was in instantiated inside the contructor of a class Student